# Cant find the java projects window in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I'm on vscode with the extension `Project Manager for Java` but i can only occasionally see the java projects window on the side bar. I check the three dots, nothing. Open view, nothing. The extension is on and enabled. I would show images, but the photos I took apparently take too much space. I can't figure out a difinitive way to restart vscode or the extension, just closing/disabling and opening/enabling

Comment: Could you share some screenshots?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, so turns out you have to open a java file. THEN it opens all the java extensions. That's really dumb and I hope they change that at some point.